# Best Practice for C++ Function Pointers/Callbacks

Tags: c++

I'm looking for some guidance in terms of best practices when dealing with custom callbacks or function pointers.

I have two main use cases right now.

1. I have a blocking loop inside my class that loops forever. I want an external user to be able to specify a function that gets called on each iteration of that loop.

Ex.

```
myClass.setLoopFunction(doStuff);
```

Where doStuff is a function located elsewhere that will get called on each iteration of the loop.

1. I get back an int from a function that can correspond to multiple values. I want to dynamically map functions to those values so I can just do a lookup on the int I get back and then call the corresponding function.

Ex.

```
myFunctionMap[passedInt]();
```

Where the int acts as a key to lookup the correct function to call.

I know my syntax here is probably off and I will need to use a std::map and be passing pointers etc, but any help, guidance or pitfalls would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have the following declared for now as a public variable:

```
class Window {

public:
//The processing function can be from any class and takes in no arguments and returns void
template<class T>
std::function<void(T*, void)> processingFunction;

};
```

The functionality I want to have is that any class can pass in a function that takes in 0 arguments and returns void and I will set that as my processing function. In the while loop, I will execute that processingFunction and it will call the member function on that original class.

```
while(true) {
    if (exitCondition == false) {
        //Execute processing function
        processingFunction();
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm completely missing something with templates, std::function and/or std::bind. Then again it's been a good four hours of scouring the internet so maybe I just need to sleep on it.

Comment: So I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CPPCallback.aspx and it basically does everything I need it to do and at what seems to be a performant rate. Why reinvent the wheel right? I still want to explore this code more to really understand it but for now it solves my purposes. Thanks all for the help/guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you use `std::function< void() >` instead of pointers. Note that this is a TR1 addition to the standard library, you can use Boost implementation of it to work on older implementations. The benefit of it is that it takes any kind of function that takes no arguments and returns something compatible with `void` (that is: returns anything). You can use it in conjuntion with `std::bind` to get even more flexibility.

That said, you would still need an `std::map< int, std::function< void() > >` (or an ordinary `std::vector` if your indices are sequential) to map from indices to functions.

Comment: Cool, I will give that a go tonight. Are there any performance implications I should worry about? More so for the callback in my infinite while loop than the map.

Comment: @Jon: Well yes, at least with the Boost function implementation each call is equivalent to two regular function calls or something like that. It's all explained in their rationale for avoiding virtual dispatch.

Comment: Hmmmn. This appears to be more difficult than i thought. [EDIT] Removed comments due to formatting and edited my original question instead.

Comment: While not exactly the solution I needed, it wasn't that this answer was wrong, rather that I couldn't make it work due to lack of understanding in how to use std::function and bind properly. Still get's the checkmark since it led me to my solution of using the Callback library above.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you define the callback to include a `void *` parameter, which the caller specifies when they install the callback. This allows the caller to pass arbitrary data into their callback, which is often needed to provide context to that function. Callers not needing this parameter can use NULL to provide it.

Comment: This is so C... there are much better ways in C++!

Comment: Using `void*` is almost always a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your callback eventually calls back into GUI-accessing code, you might need to dispatch control to the GUI thread ( `Control.Invoke()` and `Control.BeginInvoke` do this in .NET's WinForms ). That might cause deadlocks, so watch out.
2. As a generalization of the previous point, remember that during a callback call, your loop function won't be able to handle requests. So in the callback function, do as little work as possible, or spawn another thread if you need to do cpu-intensive stuff. And try to avoid calling blocking functions as well.
3. Don't forget to unregister the callback ( `myClass.setLoopFunction(NULL)` ) once you no longer need it, and checking if it's set before you call it from the loop. This is optional, I just do it in order to provide a smoother cleanup. You might skip this if your loop needs high performance.
4. What @K-ballo said. About @mah's suggestion, it could be done using an interface or templates instead